# Javascript . date

Tags: дата, javascript

вывести сколько дней осталось до 8 марта.
что я делаю не так?

```
var a=new Date(), b=new Date(), c=new Date(), d, e, f, s1, s2;
b.setDate(7);
b.setMonth(3);
b.getYear();
d=Date.parse(a);
e=Date.parse(b);
if (d<e) {b.setFullYear(b.getFullYear+1)}
e=Date.parse(b);
s1=Math.floor((d-e)/1000/60/60/24);
alert("do 8 marta dney"+s1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно указываете номер месяца, в javascript они начинаются с 0 ( 0 - январь, 2 - март ).
Если брать известную дату, то код можно слегка упростить:

```
var currentDate = new Date(),
    needDate = new Date(2014, 2, 8),
    remainingDays = Math.ceil( ( needDate - currentDate ) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 );
    alert( remainingDays );
```